# Category slug not showing for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, urls, slug

I have a Custom Post Type called 'shows' which makes use of the default Wordpress Category function.

I can see my 'shows' posts on `/category/%postname%` URL's, but when I post the URL the slug looks like this:

[image]

Any idea why `/shows/%category/%postname%` isn't pulling in the category? Live URL's look like this:

[image]

Comment: How's it making use of the category taxonomy? Can you please post the code showing how your CPT is registering the taxonomy for use? Do you have "register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category','shows');" in there?

Answer (score 0):

I see in your screenshot that the URL displays `%CAtegory%`.

You'll want to go back and make sure your custom permalink is set to `%category%`. The syntax for populating the URL with the category appears to be case-sensitive.